# Loop through Vault secret

Tags: go, hashicorp-vault, vault

I'm trying to use Vault annotation's template to create a secret file with `key: value` structure.

Currently I'm trying with this:

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-credentials.txt: |
  {{ with secret (print "secret/data/test/config/") }}{{ range $k, $v := .Data.data }}
  {{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
  {{ end }}
```

But this results is Vault's init container error. The secret itself looks like this:

```
data        map[test1:test1 test2:test2 test3:test3]
metadata    map[created_time:2022-09-04T23:47:42.299009227Z custom_metadata:<nil> deletion_time: destroyed:false version:2]
```

And the output structure should look like that (`key: value`):

```
test1: test1
test2: test2
test3: test3
```

How can I achieve that?

**[EDIT]**

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-credentials.txt: |
  {{- with secret (print "secret/data/test/config") }}{{- range $k, $v := .Data.data }}
  {{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
  {{- end }}{{- end }}
```

This works well but it produces new line at the beginning of the file:

```
// one empty line at the beginning
test1: test1
test2: test2
test3: test3
```

Comment: It looks like your `.Data.data` has two keys: `data` and `metadata`. Try iterating `.Data.data.data`

Comment: Still I'm getting `template.server: template server error: error="(dynamic): parse: template: :4: unexpected EOF"`

Comment: I've added `{{ end }}` at the end but now the generated file is empty

Comment: It worked with `.Data.data` but there are strange new lines in the generated file after every key: value line

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the line break you have to start the file after the `|` directly

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-credentials.txt: | {{- with secret (print "secret/data/test/config") }}{{- range $k, $v := .Data.data }}
{{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
{{- end }}{{- end }}
```

i suggest using template `source` and `destination` [src](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/agent/template)